Infinispan getting error Failed acquiring lock
I'm using infispan for caching with spring boot application and gradle as build tool. In developing environment with intellij idea First startup of the application working fine without any error, but second time when I'm trying to run applicaton it getting below error.
Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: ISPN029025: Failed acquiring lock 'FileSystemLock{directory=.\cache1\0\RT12-CACHE, file=RT12-CACHE.lck}' for SIFS
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.internalStart(DefaultCacheManager.java:781)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.start(DefaultCacheManager.java:746)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:412)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:361)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:336)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.<init>(DefaultCacheManager.java:324)

only using /local-cache-configuration as below
      <local-cache-configuration name="default-template-1" statistics="true">
            <expiration lifespan="129600000"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="./cache1/1"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache-configuration>

        <local-cache-configuration name="template-no-cache" statistics="true">
            <expiration lifespan="0"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="./cache1/0"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache-configuration>

        <local-cache-configuration name="template-60-min-cache" statistics="true">
            <expiration lifespan="3600000"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="./cache1/0"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache-configuration>

        <local-cache-configuration name="template-1-min-cache" statistics="true">
            <expiration lifespan="60000"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="./cache1/0"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache-configuration>

        <local-cache-configuration name="template-10-min-cache" statistics="true">
            <expiration lifespan="600000"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="./cache1/0"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache-configuration>

        <local-cache-configuration name="template-20-sec-cache" statistics="true">
            <expiration lifespan="20000"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="./cache1/1"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache-configuration>

        <local-cache-configuration name="template-cm-3" statistics="true">
            <!--            for 60 minutes-->
            <expiration lifespan="3600000"/>
            <persistence>
                <file-store path="./cache1/1"/>
            </persistence>
        </local-cache-configuration>

versions:

spring boot 3.2.2
infinispan-spring-boot-starter-embedded 14.0.28.Final
infinispan-core 15.0.3.Final

But after deleting the cache folder I can run the application without any error.  Now every time I run the application I have to delete the cache folder.
I'm looking for a solution for running application without every time deleting the cache folder

do you have a small reproducer for this? I created a project with the given information but didn't hit the problem. Additionally, why the misaligned Infinispan versions?
To give more context. This locking issue happens when the application has a hard crash or a misconfiguration somewhere in the application, creating multiple instances of the Infinispan cache manager pointing to the same data folder.
On shutdown, Spring invokes all the procedures registered by beans to run on stop. This shutdown includes cleaning the lock file. Even if CTRL-C the application, Spring would execute the shutdown process.
It is not optimal, but deleting the file ending with .lck on the cache's data folder should be enough.

I encountered this issue when using Infinispan version 15.0.4.Final with Spring Boot 3.3.0 where locks were not removed after forcefully killing the process, although they were removed if the process was gracefully killed. I managed to resolve this problem by downgrading to Infinispan version 15.0.2.Final. As per my observation, global file system locks are not added in this version.

For me, 15.0.7.Final (the current version) also seems to solve the issue.
